# flex actionscript Retriving alpha value of canvas background.

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, alpha

Can we fetch the alpha value from a canvas( i have a canvas in flex, setting background color with alpha, can i read the alpha from the canvas directly again later ? ) for example we can read the background color like canvasId.getStyle(backgroundColor) same way, any method for alpha as well ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#alpha) is a property of DisplayObject which means you can set/get it at any time like any other property. backgroundAlpha is a style which you can also get at any time, but you have to call canvas.getStyle("backgroundAlpha") just like you would with the backgroundColor style.